# MultiArray unsetting values assistance needed

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array named `$mark_ary` which contains this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 61
    [1] => 62
    [2] => 63
    [3] => 64
    [4] => 65
    [5] => 66
    [6] => 67
    [7] => 68
)
```

And another variable named `$special_donors_array` which contains this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 4
            [user_id] => 61
            [group_leader] => 0
            [user_pending] => 0
            [username] => tester_8
            [username_clean] => tester_8
            [user_email] => tester_8@live.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 5
            [user_id] => 62
            [group_leader] => 0
            [user_pending] => 0
            [username] => tester_9
            [username_clean] => tester_9
            [user_email] => tester_9@live.com
        )

)
```

I need to take every `[user_id]` value from each parent key ([0] and [1] in this case) of the `$special_donors_array` variable, and use those numbers to **UNSET** them from the `$mark_ary` array variable.

After I achieve what I want, the `$mark_ary` variable would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 63
    [3] => 64
    [4] => 65
    [5] => 66
    [6] => 67
    [7] => 68
)
```

Unfortunately, I can't even think of a solution and I couldn't even try a think because I didn't know how to start this. I still need to gain some more array related knowledge.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($special_donors_array as $special_donor){
                foreach($mark_ary as $k => $mark){
                    if($mark == $special_donor['user_id']){
                        unset($mark_ary[$k]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: using `isset` is better (performance-wise), than using an extra `foreach`

Comment: And where am I checking the key??

Comment: isset($mark_ary[$k]) - here. Trully reread problem carefully. I did same solution as you in first place and then I noticed the misinterpretation.

Comment: like i said before, the key isset check is coz I assumed that both arrays are of sizes

Comment: Why did you assume that? Dugi did not say anything lke that, he said he need to unset $mark_ary element which value is present in user_id field of second array. Value of $mark_ary not key!

Comment: it was a misinterpretation, i'm sure you will have your days too. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $special_donors_array as $k => $v ) {
 if( isset($mark_ary[$k]) && $v['user_id'] === $mark_ary[$k] )
  unset($mark_ary[$k]);
}
```

Comment: in what sense? isset saves a foreach loop, considering that both $special_donors_array & $mark_ary are of the same size. thats the only  assumption in my answer, which is different from urs.

Comment: Yes it saves the foreach loop but in addition it's not doing what Dugi want's to achieve.

Comment: like i said before, the key isset check is coz I assumed that both arrays are of sizes.